# read.xlsx ERROR: expecting a single value

Tags: java, r, xlsx

i'm trying to read an excel file with 5 worksheet by:

```
df_sheet <- xlsx::read.xlsx(lane_info, sheetIndex = 1, startRow=5 ,colIndex = 1:8,as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

when *lane_info*  is the full path to the file.

later on i'm adding another worksheet to the file:

```
wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(lane_info) # load the file
sheets <- xlsx::getSheets(wb)
newSheet <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName=new_sheet)
xlsx::addDataFrame(SampleSheet, newSheet,col.names = FALSE,row.names = FALSE)
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, lane_info)
```

everything goes well for the first time. than when i'm trying to run the script again on the same file i get the Error:

> Error in read.xlsx.default(xlsxFile = xlsxFile, sheet = sheet,
>   startRow = startRow,  :    expecting a single value

google seems to pin the cause with a file name ending with a number, which is not my case.

any thoughts?

Comment: May be because you try to add  a sheet with already used name?

Comment: my code include reading all tabs and add a suffix to distinct between existing name and a new one